# Any laravel expert here? [ file_get_contents(url) failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]

Tags: php, laravel, svg

I'm facing this while running laravel project

**ErrorException
file_get_contents(http://r4u.com/storage/app/public/Frontassets/images/icon/email.svg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found (View: /home/hamza/Documents/reserved4you/resources/views/Includes/Front/header.blade.php)**

Can you please help me out with this? I'm using "laravel/framework": "^7.29"

#laravel_experts

Comment: This is nothing to do with Laravel, the URL you're trying to call simply doesn't exist - that's what a 404 error means. Visit the URL in your browser and the same problem occurs. If you're expecting it to work, then double-check...maybe you made a typing error in the URL or something.

Comment: P.s. stackoverflow doesn't do hashtags.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have stored svg file inside storage folder of laravel.
Have you linked your storage folder in public?
If not then please run below command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And try like this `http://r4u.com/storage/Frontassets/images/icon/email.svg`

Answer (score -1):

It's looking you don't have **header blade** file inside **resources/views** folder so please check there is is available or not.

if it's available and still not working so please share your controller code if possible so that I can help you more.

thanks

Comment: No that's not what the error means. It's the call to file_get_contents which failed

Comment: okay please share your code/logic whatever you are using, so that it will be more clear and I can help you easily.